# CSS Not showing background (overflow:auto not helping)

Tags: html, css, background, invisible

The background and border of #navigation_conatiner_7 are not visible. I tried adding overflow:auto to its parent, and it just displays scroll bars. Later I tried adding the same to it, but then it is completely hidden. Since I have run out of ideas, I thought maybe someone here might have the answer.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Tamaki/my5GV/

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="navigation_category_2">articles</div>
        <div id="navigation_category_3">columns</div>
        <div id="navigation_category_7">submit
            <div id="navigation_container_7">
                <div class="navigation_link"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">submit</span></div>
                <div class="navigation_link"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">applications</span></div>
                <div class="navigation_link"><span style="margin-left: 10px;">points</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation {
    top: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #dd6a0c;
    position: fixed;
}

#holder {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
}

/* Navigation
============================*/

#navigation_category_2, #navigation_category_3, #navigation_category_7 {
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 7px 0 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-family: Impact, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#navigation_category_2:hover, #navigation_category_3:hover, #navigation_category_7:hover {
    background-color: #dd6a0c;
    color: #eee;
}

#navigation_category_7:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #111;
}

#navigation_container_7 {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    width: 160px;
    left: -24px;
    border: 3px solid #dd6a0c;
    border-top: none;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

#navigation_category_7:hover #navigation_container_7 {
    display: block;
}

.navigation_link {
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #111;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navigation_link:hover {
    background-color: #dd6a0c;
    color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: For me it works. What OS/Browser are you using ?

Comment: There is a reason why you need do post some code before you can add some link.

Comment: I am using Window 8/Chrome 29.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `height=0px` from `#navigation_conatiner_7`

Comment: That was the issue, thank you! (I was experimenting with height animations and forgot to remove that)

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in following id :

```
 #navigation_category_7:hover {
        background-color: #dd6a0c;
        color: #111;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the code was that the color you saw was actually derived from the links pasted inside container.

Added this

```
#navigation_category_7 #navigation_container_7 .navigation_link {
background-color: #eee;
}
```

and it works now. Check http://jsfiddle.net/my5GV/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the css:

```
#navigation_category_2:hover, #navigation_category_3:hover, #navigation_category_7:hover {
    background-color: #dd6a0c;
    color: #eee;
}

#navigation_category_7:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #111;
}
```

to this

```
#navigation_category_2:hover, #navigation_category_3:hover {//you were calling #navigation_category_7 here to
    background-color: #dd6a0c;
    color: #eee;
}

#navigation_category_7:hover {
    background-color: #eee; //this color is giving you the error, change if to 6 letter or rgba
    color: #111;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be using 's for menus.
Try using the ul and li tags instead
something like this:

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="LINK">MENU#1</a></li>
    <li><a href="LINK">MENU#2</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
            <li><a href="LINK">MENU#3</a>
                <ul class="submenu-2">
                    <li><a href="LINK">MENU#4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="LINK">MENU#5</a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
            <li><a href="LINK">MENU#6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul li {
    // All menus li
}
ul li ul { // All submenus
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
ul li ul li { // All submenus li

}
ul.submenu-1 { // UL > LI > UL

}
ul.submenu-2 { // UL > LI > UL > LI > UL

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I prefer it this way. There are no actual rules for what I should use, are there?

Comment: It's a standard that most people use.
 
CMS's and frameworks (Wordpress for example). Automatically create the ul and li tags for you when creating a menu. It's usually better to get used to standards than try to fight them

Answer (score -1):

change

```
#navigation_category_2:hover,
#navigation_category_3:hover, 
#navigation_category_7:hover {
background-color: #dd6a0c;
color: #eee;
}
```

to

```
#navigation_category_2:hover,
#navigation_category_3:hover, 
#navigation_category_7:hover {
background-color: #dd6a0c !important;
color: #eee !important;
}
```

just add !important to prevent from overwritting.

Comment: She repetitively use  #navigation_category_7:hover ID

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya : all she wants is to get bg of #navigation_category_7 ??
if she is repetitively using #navigation_category_7:hover it will overwrite other properties.

Comment: Excuse me, but I only used #navigation_category_7 where needed, its presence is minimized in the code. If you took a second to look at it, you would have noticed that.